# AttributeError at /items/1094 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, django

Делаю сайт на джанго, запарсил элементы в базу данных, пытаюсь сделать страницу конкретного элемента, но не получается.
Вот что пишет Traceback

```
AttributeError at /items/1094
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/1094
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: C:\Users\ae785\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py in process_response, line 26
Python Executable:  C:\Users\ae785\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\ae785\\Desktop\\foxD\\fox\\fox\\apps',
 'C:\\Users\\ae785\\Desktop\\foxD\\fox',
 'C:\\Users\\ae785\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\ae785\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\ae785\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\ae785\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\ae785\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django import urls
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('/<int:item_id>', views.current_item, name='current_item')
]
```

******views.py**

```
def current_item(request, item_id):
    a = item.objects.get(id = item_id)
    
    return 'current_item/current_item.html'
```

Comment: добавьте код включающий модели. и откуда у вас item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в

```
return 'current_item/current_item.html'
```

я неправильно использовал эту функцию, мне нужно было написать

```
return (request,'current_item/current_item.html')
```